# Wrong attribute value getting passed to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just noticed in my database that inside the Receipts table it is not showing the proper `recipient_id` for the `receiver_id` column. I am working between the Questions, Conversations and Receipts table with the Mailboxer gem.

For example here's the issue:

A new entry in the Questions table appears with the

> `id` 552, `sender_id` 1, and `recipient_id` 2.

2 new entrys is then made in the Receipts table that's associated with the Questions entry just created (creates 2 entrys by default, one for recipient and other for sender). The details for the

> first entry is `id` 547 and `receiver_id` 552.
>
> The second entry `id` is 548 and `receiver_id` 1.

As you can see for the first entry the `receiver_id` is being copied from the Questions table `id`. It should be transferring the Questions table `recipient_id` instead.

I have no idea at how to fix this.

Questions controller:

```
 def create
      @question = Question.new(params[:question])
      if @question.save
        @message = current_user.send_message(@question, @question.question, "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}") 
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
      else
        render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
      end
    end
  end
```

Question model:

```
  acts_as_messageable

  attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :conversation_id
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :sender,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key => 'sender_id'

  belongs_to :recipient,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

  belongs_to :message

  belongs_to :conversation
```

show.html.slim:

```
center
  .message_div
    = form_for Question.new, class: 'question_form form-horizontal', role: 'form' do |f|
      .form-group
        = f.text_field :question, {:placeholder => 'Please add your question...',class:'form-control'}
      = f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => current_user.id
      = f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => @user.id
      = f.submit 'Ask Question', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

schema.rb:

```
create_table "receipts", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "receiver_id"
    t.string   "receiver_type"
    t.integer  "notification_id",                            null: false
    t.boolean  "is_read",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "trashed",                    default: false
    t.boolean  "deleted",                    default: false
    t.string   "mailbox_type",    limit: 25
    t.datetime "created_at",                                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                 null: false
  end

  add_index "receipts", ["notification_id"], name: "index_receipts_on_notification_id", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "receipts", "notifications", name: "receipts_on_notification_id"
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-08 17:00:12 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nYOcY69oD6WcfNGEJcKGpyupA0CNbYnAJz0SQ+dKtEk=", "question"=>{"question"=>"Stack Overflow can you help me out?", "sender_id"=>"3", "recipient_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Ask Question"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = 'HkI7Lm4fJYHHf5LHEcMtvA' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `questions` (`created_at`, `question`, `recipient_id`, `sender_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-08-08 21:00:12', 'Stack Overflow can you help me out?', 2, 3, '2014-08-08 21:00:12')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `conversations` (`created_at`, `subject`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-08-08 21:00:12', 'You have a question from 3', '2014-08-08 21:00:12')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `notifications` (`attachment`, `body`, `conversation_id`, `created_at`, `sender_id`, `sender_type`, `subject`, `type`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, 'Stack Overflow can you help me out?', 419, '2014-08-08 21:00:12', 3, 'User', 'You have a question from 3', 'Message', '2014-08-08 21:00:12')
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `receipts` (`created_at`, `mailbox_type`, `notification_id`, `receiver_id`, `receiver_type`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-08-08 21:00:12', 'inbox', 459, 577, 'Question', '2014-08-08 21:00:12')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `receipts` (`created_at`, `is_read`, `mailbox_type`, `notification_id`, `receiver_id`, `receiver_type`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-08-08 21:00:12', 1, 'sentbox', 459, 3, 'User', '2014-08-08 21:00:12')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/user
Completed 302 Found in 562ms (ActiveRecord: 62.3ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the Reciept model and controller (assuming thats where the incorrect values are being assigned). Also if you could post the params being passes into the controller

Comment: @ob264 There is no receipt model or controller. Mailboxer gem does not instruct that you do (reviewing the post and I noticed I never mentioned the gem).

Comment: Why are you saving the question twice in your `create` method?

Comment: @EgeErsoz Oops that slip by me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `send_message` in your controller, you pass `@question` as a recipient. It means that the first receipt is indeed built with the `question_id` as `receiver_id`. But from what I understand, you want the question's recipient to be sent the message. Simply replace your send_message call with:

```
current_user.send_message(@question.recipient, @question.question, "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}")
```

**What's happening behind the scene**

The Receipt table from mailboxer can be considered as a proof that a notification has been sent. In your model, by adding

```
acts_as_messageable
```

You include the `Messageable` module described in the mailboxer documentation, including the following `send_message` method:

```
def send_message(recipients, msg_body, subject, sanitize_text=true, attachment=nil, message_timestamp = Time.now)
  # message = ...
  # message building stuff happening

  message.deliver false, sanitize_text
end
```

When you call that method from your controller, it calls the deliver method on this newly created message. Here's the interesting bits of that method, extracted from the mailboxer documentation:

```
def deliver(reply = false, should_clean = true)
  # ... some stuff

  #Receiver receipts
  temp_receipts = recipients.map { |r| build_receipt(r, 'inbox') }

  #Sender receipt
  sender_receipt = build_receipt(sender, 'sentbox', true)

  temp_receipts << sender_receipt

  if temp_receipts.all?(&:save!)
    # some other stuff
  end
  sender_receipt
end
```

As you can see `temp_receipts = recipients.map { |r| build_receipt(r, 'inbox') }` builds a receipt for every recipient of the message.

The second interesting line `sender_receipt = build_receipt(sender, 'sentbox', true)` builds a receipt for **the sender**. Which in your case is the `current_user`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great information and well explained. I swear I tried question.recipient and was receiving a error when I did it. I must of misspelled it or something. Nevertheless it works and you made me understand Mailboxer a lot more. Thanks!